# Why is my jQuery code not working when I click the button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm fairly new to JavaScript/jQuery and web programming. I have to textboxes and a button. I'm trying to make it so that when the textboxes have the right characters in them and you click the button, it takes you to another page. But when I click the button, nothing happens.

Here is a link to it on my server: http://jakadproductions.com/testing/

Sorry, I'm only 15.

My code:

```js
$document.ready(function() {
  $("#login_button").click(function() {
    var username_value = document.getElementById("username_box").value;
    var password_value = document.getElementById("password_box").value;
    if (username_value == "JakobMorelan" && password_value == "Admin1234") {
      window.location = "http://jakadproductions.com/naj7m6j2aajre1o7opjr/";
    };
    else {
      window.location = "http://jakadproductions.com/";
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<title>LOGIN</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<h1>LOGIN</h1>
<input id="username_box" type="textbox" placeholder="Username" />
<input id="password_box" type="textbox" placeholder="Password" />
<button id="login_button">Submit</button>
```

Comment: take the `;`'s off of the closing brackets in your `if` condition. Your browser should have a developer console where you will see syntax errors like that.

Comment: Please confirm, you are writing this as an exercise for yourself and not to really hide anything valuable behind a javascript link obfuscator.

Comment: To clarify my comment above. Everyone can read your javascript code. Thus anyone can **very easily** bypass this "login" mechanism.

Comment: @wedi I'm really new to it it, so I'm just playing around. If I were to build an actual login, it would be server side instead.

Comment: Follow Michael Coker comment, your java script has syntax errors

Comment: @JakobMorelan Cool. Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 1):

The console is your friend. Looking at it would reveal this:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'else'

Given you only have one else keyword in your code, you can assume it's that one. Immediately before that you have a semicolon which completely ends that conditional. Therefore the else is invalid because there's no longer an if that it's continuing from. Remove the semicolon and it will run.

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra semi-colon after `if`

```
if (username_value == "JakobMorelan" && password_value == "Admin1234") {
                window.location = "http://jakadproductions.com/naj7m6j2aajre1o7opjr/";
            }
            else {
                window.location = "http://jakadproductions.com/";
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if/else block has an additional `;` where none is expected!

Try and open the developer tools of your browser, it should give you a hint if there is something wrong with your code and a pointer to where the error is.

In this case remove the `;` after the if statement

Answer (score 0):

The browser debugger is a great tool to figure out these issues. When I opened the link to your testing page and opened the browser's debug tool it spit out the problem:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else
```

It's saying that it doesn't expect the else token because you put a semi colon after the if clause ending it. Since there was no if statement that was still ongoing the else was unexpected and the script crashed

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is an error in the code. After your if statement (and before the else) you have put a semicolon ';'. First fix that, CTRL + SHIFT + J opens a console on Chrome, you can use to debug this kind of errors easily

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have two errors in your code—

1. As others have mentioned, you have to remove the semicolon after your `if {...}` block. In JavaScript and many other languages, the standard syntax is `if {...} else {...}`.
2. Your jQuery code begins with `$document`, where—unless `var $document` has been previously defined—you really need `$(document)`. The `document` variable is globally available and doesn't itself need to be defined, but to use it with jQuery methods like `.ready(...)`, you have to wrap it in the jQuery wrapper, which is what `$(document)` does.

Here's a Codepen example of it working. I have changed the redirects to alerts.

https://codepen.io/ericpedia/pen/qmmvNJ

Comment: I do have one more question though. I can't get the browser to redirect to a different page when the button is clicked. Not sure why. Do you know possibly? @supertrue

Comment: If you mean it doesn't redirect in the Codepen example, that's because the redirect fails in the Codepen context due to security/iframe considerations. If that's not what you mean, you may need to prevent the default form submission behavior (which is often to load another page) inside your `.click` function. 

To do this, pass in the `event` variable, like this: `.click(function(event)...` and add `event.preventDefault();` to the beginning of the function. Let me know if it works.